# How to kill Ngrok tunnel from Google Colab Notebook

Tags: ngrok, streamlit, google-colaboratory, pyngrok

I am running *Streamlit* app from *Google Colab Notebook*.

Due to some limitations of sending out the URL of *Streamlit* app to outside, I follow the tutorial of using *Ngrok* for sending URL via tunnel.

I know that with a *single ngrok client session*, I can't run more than one tunnel. But in my case, I want to rerun and reconnect my Streamlit app to ngrok again.

So in order to do so, I want to kill the *running Ngrok tunnel* first.

So please anyone, could you tell me how to *kill ngrok* from *Colab Notebook*?

Comment: Is [ngrok.disconnect()](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pyngrok.ngrok.disconnect) or [ngrok.kill()](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pyngrok.ngrok.kill) not working? Both should accomplish this.

Comment: It's because when I was googling about how to kill Ngrok from Colab, there's seem no specific answer (from blog or medium) for the question. There're other kind of methods to kill ngrok by using javascript or other way around but not from Colab command itself. So I asked this question here.
Now I am trying your method, and it works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you have an orphaned Colab. Go to Runtime -> Manage Sessions, and terminate all of them and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the processes on which ngrok tunnel is running and kill it.

command to find the processes ids

`ps -eaf | grep {{port on which ngrok is running}}`

This will result in a list of processes that has a text match with the port number. Identify the ngrok tunnel processes and kill those processes running the following command

`sudo kill -9 {{process id}}`